# Bubble Sort Ascending Comparison & Swap Count

Tags: algorithm, compare, swap, bubble-sort

We are studying algorithms and we haven't yet started making any programs with it, so we have a simple exercises. For example:

I have to bubble sort:
4 2 7 16 6

Here is a proccess (we have to look from the right to left in this case):

```
4 2 7 16  6       (it makes 3 swaps and 4 comparisons in this)
2 4 6  7 16       (it makes 0 swaps and 3 comparison  in this)
2 4 6  7 16       (the result)
```

This how I understand it:

```
4 2 7 16 6  (6 is swapped with 16) 
4 2 7 6 16  (6 is swapped with 7)
4 2 6 7 16  (6 is not swapped with 2)
4 2 6 7 16  (2 is swapped with 4)
2 4 6 7 16  (result after 1st iteration)
```

now we have numbers which have been arranged properly, we have made **4 comparisons** at the beginning and 3 swaps and we know that 2 is the smallest number so we will look at 4 6 7 16 now. However they are arranged properly but still we have to make **3 additional** 
comparisons.

My question is: do we have to make **another 2 comparisons and then the last 1 comparison** (which would result in 10 comparisons overall) to finish the bubble sort? Or it **stops after 7?**

I'm not sure when the Bubble-sort stops.

Comment: They are many variant of bubble sort. We can't answer unless you show us the (pseudo)-code of the one you are using. Also, SO is **not** a homework solving site. We help you if you have program to debug, but we don't write or explain program for you.

Comment: It's not the homework. I just made the numbers up. I am preparing for the exam.
English is not my primary language. So I can't exactly translate everything properly. 
I am aware of 4 variations of bubble sort. I will edit my OP.

Comment: So from your example, I think even if the number is in its correct position, you will still do the comparison right? So for '2','4','6', you still have to count their comparisons based on your example?

Comment: Shole, you are right. I am not sure when we need to stop the bubble sort. I updated my OP.
Hivert, I would not think of any other way to show my problem. Like I said, my vocabulary is not the best.

Comment: The problem is not the answer of the exercise.
The problem is I'm not sure if it still compares all the numbers even though the sequence of numbers is already correct.

Comment: I think yes, because you cannot know one number is already in its final position if you do not do the comparisons in this case. For eg, when you trying to put number '6', what we see is the sequence is already sorted, and what the algorithm see is '? ? 6 7 16', so it has to do the comparison...